# Quicksort gives stackoverflow on constant numbers but not on random numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I feel very confused about why this C++ code snippet acts differently when I assign the array value with `rand()` or with any constant value.

```
const int MIN_SIZE = 10000;
const int MAX_SIZE = 100000;

int main()
{
  for(j = MIN_SIZE; j <= MAX_SIZE; j += MIN_SIZE) {
    int *arrPtr = new int[j];
    for(int i = 0; i < j; i++)
       arrPtr[i] = 1; //When I put rand() here, it works fine but in any constant it gives stack overflow
    quickSort(arr, 0, j - 1);
    delete []arrPtr;
  }
}
```

The code above basically creates a dynamically allocated array with `j` as size, which gets incremented by `MIN_SIZE`(10,000) in each turn and assigns some specific integers to each indexes. After the assignment it sorts with quicksort algorithms of which I'm going to provide mine below and then deallocates this array when its done. This whole thing repeats up to `MAX_SIZE`(100,000).

Here's my Quicksort code:

```
void quickSort(int *arr, int front, int rear)
{
    if (front < rear)
    {
        int part = partition(arr, front, rear);
        quickSort(arr, front, part - 1);
        quickSort(arr, part + 1, rear);
    }
}

int partition(int *arr, int front, int rear)
{
    int element = arr[rear];
    int i = front - 1;
    for (int j = front; j<rear; ++j)
    {
        if (arr[j] <= element)
        {
            ++i;
            long temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
    }
    long temp = arr[i + 1];
    arr[i + 1] = arr[rear];
    arr[rear] = temp;
    return i + 1;
}
```

I'm trying to implement quicksort algorithm which strictly uses the ***last item as pivot***. In this case I'm facing with a strange problem: when I assign each value of the array to a random number using `rand()` function, everything works just fine, however, when I enter a constant value, the size of the array goes up to 4039(when you manipulate MAX_SIZE and MIN_SIZE) then gives a **stack overflow** error. I am really confused, why on earth that would cause a problem, besides, why 4039?

Comment: Check the return value of partition. I'd guess you have a run a way recursion due to partition returning a wrong value, resulting in quicksorting the whole array over and over.

Comment: Is this homework? If it is then there is a lot of help regarding quicksort on the 'Net and on SO. Otherwise... Use `vector` and the inbuilt `sort` algorithm. 9 times out of 10 it will be faster than what you can write.

Comment: When all elements of the array are the same is a corner case case of the array already being sorted, and if the array is already sorted then you get a worst-case scenario with quicksort. [See this for an explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, I'm actually doing it deliberately, to test its performance and collect some data in terms of number of comparisons of data swaps etc. Yet, Its interesting that this problem occurs. Any suggestion?

Comment: @DanielJour But why on 4039, isn't it strange? do you catch any particular problem in my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quicksort that uses the last element as a pivot element is expected to overflow the stack for equal elements when implemented in a straightforward manner. This is how quicksort works. It is a "defect" in the algorithm.

To see why just look at how the recursive function calls are created.

```
quicksort(arr, 0, 100)  - will produce the recursive calls
   quicksort(arr, 0, 99); and
   quicksort(arr, 100, 100);
```

The problem is that the `quicksort(arr, 0, 99);` will recurse for every element in the array.

In your case your stack was full at 4039 elements. You seem to have about 8 integers worth of state in each of your calls, that will give you a hint on the max size of your stack. I'm guessing about 1 MB.

This is not the case with random ints as the depth of the recursive calls will be evenly distributed between the left and the right part of the recursion. This desired behavior makes the recursive depth approach log N. For your MAX_SIZE this is a depth of about 17, instead of 100000. This is the reason quicksort is described as an N log N algorithm. The first N is from the partitioning.

Comment: So we shouldn't be using the last element as pivot, it will eventually cause stack overflow then.. for some cases.. but what differs when we use rand() or a straightforward constant. My program ran flawlessly when I assigned the values using rand(), however, at first sight, those constant values that I assigned manually seemed to me that were causing the problem. Yet I give you credit about the last pivot bug you're right.

Comment: Don't recurse for biggest interval, just for smaller interval (tail recursion optimization)

Comment: @Burak. If the array contains random values the pivot will not be the last element.

Comment: The problem is that arr[end] doesn't split the array in two "halves".. My librarys `std::sort` for instance switches to a different sorting method when it encounters excessive recursion depth.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg you're right it only becomes the last element when the array is already sorted in ascending manner. how about descending order then? it still throws the exception.

Comment: @Burak. the effect is exactly the same, just from the other end of the array.

Answer (score 2):

A constant array with an end-pivot and splitting the array into two results in a recursion depth of "number of elements in the array", and O(n^2) time.

There are many ways around this.

First, partition the array into 3 components.  Greater, Less, and *Equal* to partition.  The equal goes between.  This fixes the corner case you ran into.  It increases the constant factor, but the quicksort cost becomes O(n lg m) where m is the number of distinct elements as a bonus.

Sorted arrays still die a horrible death.  Make a better partiton picker.  Random partitions make the probability of horrible behaviour near 0.  Picking 3 (or 2k+1) elements (maybe at random) and using their median is another approach.  For deterministic good behaviour, an algorithm to find an element berween the 30% and 70% mark in O(n) time is called "median of 5" (which is not just taking the median of 5 elements).

Another trick is to partition the array, recurse on the *smaller* partition, and *loop* on the bigger one.  This solves the recursion depth problem but not the runtime one.

Next, consider escape strategies for small array lengths.  Quick sort on (say) 8 elements may be seriously suboptimal compared to selection sort.  Once you have an escape strategy, you can optimisitcally use a fast and dirty quicksort (pick 3 random elements for pivot, etc) and track recursive depth.  If you pass 2*lg(n) depth, escape to provably correct quicksort (median-of-5 to find pivot).  And when you fall to less than 8 (tune this) elememts, switch to selection sort.

Finally, all of the above and more has probably already been done when you just `std::sort`.  So use it instead.

Comment: Regarding the comments on the partition step.  The original quicksort by Hoare in '62 describes a partition step with a smaller and a bigger division. The dividing element being the partitioning element. So a three division partition is not a "pure" quicksort.  The problem OP encountered was commented on in the paper as "An awkward situation is liable to arise if the value of the bound...".

Answer (score 0):

You can guarantee the stack depth of `O(log(N))` if you always recurse into the smaller half first and compiler generates tail recursion for the second call.

```
void quickSort(int *arr, int front, int rear)
{
    if (front < rear)
    {
        int part = partition(arr, front, rear);
        int a, b, c, d;
        if (part - front <= rear - part)
        {
            a = front;
            b = part - 1;
            c = part + 1;
            d = rear;
        }
        else
        {
            a = part + 1;
            b = rear;
            c = front;
            d = part - 1;
        }
        quickSort(arr, a, b);
        quickSort(arr, c, d);
    }
}
```